# How do I change my email address on Play Store as the one I have is no longer in use

Tags: google-play-store

The email address I have on Play Store is no longer verified and I wish to change to my current provider as I do not seem to be able to download apps

Comment: What do you mean "change my provider"? Its not going to change the content you can get from the play store. Just get yourself a new email address and add that into __*settings>account>*__…youll have the choice of what email address to use when you enter the play store.………are you sure that is the reason why you can't download? Did you try clearing the data/cache? Search through Stack Exchange for "non-working play store" ( I'm not at my computer now, otherwise I'd provide a link for you).

Answer (score 2):

Go to settings->accounts->add account->and add another Google account with the new email. Then go into the play store and there will be your email with a drop down arrow. Tap it and select the new email.

Comment: What Google page should I be on when I click "Settings>Account"...? Every (or nearly every) Google service has a "Settings" gear and probably a lot of them have some settings for "account". I tried this by going to play.google.com, then I clicked: "gear"->"settings". I don't see any place to add a new email address (or edit existing).